# How to get NA in one column when in column two NA occur?

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I mutate observations of e.g. skin_color to NA, when in hair_color NA occur? If would prefer a solution by using dplyr.

```
starwars %>% head()

# A tibble: 6 x 14
  name  height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender homeworld species
  <chr>  <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>  
1 Luke~    172    77 blond      fair       blue            19   male  mascu~ Tatooine  Human  
2 C-3PO    167    75 NA         gold       yellow         112   none  mascu~ Tatooine  Droid  
3 R2-D2     96    32 NA         white, bl~ red             33   none  mascu~ Naboo     Droid  
4 Dart~    202   136 none       white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu~ Tatooine  Human  
5 Leia~    150    49 brown      light      brown           19   fema~ femin~ Alderaan  Human  
6 Owen~    178   120 brown, gr~ light      blue            52   male  mascu~ Tatooine  Human 

Wanted output:

# A tibble: 6 x 14
  name  height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender homeworld species
  <chr>  <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>  
1 Luke~    172    77 blond      fair       blue            19   male  mascu~ Tatooine  Human  
2 C-3PO    167    75 NA         NA         yellow         112   none  mascu~ Tatooine  Droid  
3 R2-D2     96    32 NA         NA         red             33   none  mascu~ Naboo     Droid  
4 Dart~    202   136 none       white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu~ Tatooine  Human  
5 Leia~    150    49 brown      light      brown           19   fema~ femin~ Alderaan  Human  
6 Owen~    178   120 brown, gr~ light      blue            52   male  mascu~ Tatooine  Human
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `replace` + `is.na`?

```
> starwars %>%
+   mutate(skin_color = replace(skin_color, is.na(hair_color), NA))
# A tibble: 87 x 14
   name    height  mass hair_color  skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender
   <chr>    <int> <dbl> <chr>       <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1 Luke S~    172    77 blond       fair       blue            19   male  mascu~
 2 C-3PO      167    75 NA          NA         yellow         112   none  mascu~
 3 R2-D2       96    32 NA          NA         red             33   none  mascu~
 4 Darth ~    202   136 none        white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu~
 5 Leia O~    150    49 brown       light      brown           19   fema~ femin~
 6 Owen L~    178   120 brown, grey light      blue            52   male  mascu~
 7 Beru W~    165    75 brown       light      blue            47   fema~ femin~
 8 R5-D4       97    32 NA          NA         red             NA   none  mascu~
 9 Biggs ~    183    84 black       light      brown           24   male  mascu~
10 Obi-Wa~    182    77 auburn, wh~ fair       blue-gray       57   male  mascu~
# ... with 77 more rows, and 5 more variables: homeworld <chr>, species <chr>,
#   films <list>, vehicles <list>, starships <list>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
starwars %>% 
  mutate(skin_color = if_else(is.na(hair_color), NA_character_, skin_color)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
starwars2 <- starwars %>%
      mutate(skin_color = case_when(is.na(hair_color) ~ NA_character_, 
               TRUE~ skin_color))
```